# How do you define a single blendable design time instance?

Tags: data-binding, windows-8

The default Windows 8 project template has a CollectionViewSource in the template.

```
<CollectionViewSource
       x:Name="itemsViewSource"
       Source="{Binding Model.Invitations}"
       d:Source="{Binding Invitations, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=vm:DesignerFilteredInvitations, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}" />
```

Obviously not all pages have a collection as their model, you can define a DataContext like this:

```
<vm:MySingleItemViewModel x:Key="Model" />
```

How do you define the design instance for this kind of model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, using this works fine:

```
<Page 
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=Models:ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

And using this works fine:

```
<d:Page.DataContext>
    <Models:ViewModel/>
</d:Page.DataContext>
```

I must tell you the latter is an easier approach, too. It is also what Visual Studio will generate when you setup a data source in the designer. It also gives you fully-typed bindings. But either is acceptable.

Another note. I can see no good reason to set an object directly to the source of a CollectionViewSource. Normally you would be binding the CVS's Source property to a property inside your ViewModel. But, given your question: Here's how:

```
<CollectionViewSource 
    x:Name="TestCVS" Source="{Binding}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding Source={d:DesignInstance Type=Models:ViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>
```

Binding to the Source in the designer caused me endless trouble. But it irritated me more because I knew I would never do it this way. This is what I wanted to do:

```
<d:Page.DataContext>
    <Models:ViewModel/>
</d:Page.DataContext>

<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="TestCVS" Source="{Binding}" />
</Page.Resources>
```

You better have a great reason for your approach!

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for this, the default templates when you create a new Windows 8 project use the CollectionViewsource example as you've got it there. I was trying to match their style but they don't have the a single item source. I think you've covered all the bases here, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure why you hate it so much, but I have ViewModels and extend those with a designer version that I bind to in Blend via the d:options. They contain all the same properties but one is prepopulated for designability.

Comment: Haters love to hate; in all reality, you and I probably do the same thing. I'm likely just not communicating very well.

Answer (score 2):

Well, design time data is best accomplished like this: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/most-people-are-doing-mvvm-all-wrong.html

I realize your question is asking about using d:DesignInstance which also works with this type of technique - just not demonstrated in that article.

All it requires is a good constructor.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it doesn't answer my specific question. A useful resource though.

Comment: Let me just answer your question in this comment: a design instance does not have to be a collection. It can be a class (or View Model) and it does not have to be set to d:Source of a CVS it can be set to the d:DataContext of Page or any other FrameworkElement. You already have the syntax, you should try it and see. It works perfectly. As long as your constructor is not calling async ops or services, it will populate properly for design data.

Comment: I've tried using d:Source - it complains that "property 'Source' is not attachable to elements of type 'MyClass'". If you've actually made this work, do please let me know how.